# how to put filter on structure of attributes of xml files with spark

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, apache-spark-sql

I have a large number of xml files with large number of attributes. I want to apply a filter on the list of these files so that I can find files which contains attribute named "A" as StructType. How can I achieve this ?

```
|-- A: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

Data is like -

```
A 
[[1,X]]
```

Comment: please provide sample input and your tried codes too . And also explain your difficult part.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I've updated the question now. Please check.

Comment: so you want to filter all the rows that have "A" in C field of struct of A array?

Comment: I want to put filter on a filelist to find the files which contains column "A" in form of Struct data type.

Comment: If you want quick answers then you will have to elaborate with more details. you can give examples. it will enable others to give you answers as well.